# Drop Redshift tables latest accessed before 2 months from current time

Tags: stored-procedures, amazon-redshift

Here is the attempted stored_procedure to drop tables that have not been accessed in last 2 months.

Information_schema.tables has all the tables that are present in our redshift cluster. admin.stl_query_archive has all the queries that have run till now.

I am trying to find all the tables that are not present in the queries that have run in the last 2 months.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_drop_tables(out_var OUT varchar(256))
-- CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_drop_tables_()
AS $$
DECLARE
 r_c int := 0;
 rec record;
 tbl_rows int;
BEGIN   
  for rec in select distinct table_name from information_schema.tables
  loop
      raise info 'table_name = %', rec.table_name;
      tbl_rows := 0;
      select count(*) into tbl_rows from admin.stl_query_archive where endtime > getdate() - 61 and querytxt like '%'||quote_literal(rec.table_name)||'%';
      if tbl_rows = 0 then
        raise info 'this table is old';
      end if;
  end loop;
  select into out_var count(*) from admin.stl_query_archive;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

call sp_drop_tables()
;
```

My approach seems correct, only problem is that it throws the following error while running -

```
    Error [XX000 / 500310]: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Assert 
----------------------------------------------- error: Assert code: 1000 context: false - Unknown 
constant type to hash: 17134 query: 2122914 location: cg_hash.cpp:84 process: padbmaster [pid=124705] 
-----------------------------------------------;
```

Can anyone help me out with this? Any feedback is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which line in the procedure is generating the error?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to use quote_literal function in LIKE criteria.